How to show that $E(u+v)=E(u)E(v)$?
I'm trying to answer problem $(c)$ in Lang's Calculus book:



Using the hint he provided, as $f(x)=f'(x)$, I get that $E(u+x)=cE(x)$ but I don't know how to finish it. Can you help me?

What happens if you take $x=0$?

If you fix $u$ you obtain $E(u + v) = CE(v)$, as in your working with $x = v$. Now fix $v$ and let $u$ vary, and find $E(u + v) = DE(u)$. So now set $u = u_0$ and $v = v_0$. We have $E(u_0 + v_0) = C(u_0)E(v_0) (Equ. 1)$ and $E(u_0 + v_0) = D(v_0)E(u_0) (Equ. 2)$.
If we vary $u_0$ away from $u_0$ to $u_0 + \epsilon$, both equations $(Equ. 1)$ and $(Equ. 2)$ hold. But notice that our intial condition was the same, so $C(u_0)E(v_0) = D(v_0)E(u_0) (Equ. 4)$ in general. We can still vary $u_0$, to obtain $C(u_0) = K_1 E(u_0)$ from $(Equ. 4)$, and $D(v_0) = K_2 E(v_0)$ by varying $v_0$ similarly. But then substituting this back we get $K_1 E(u_0) E(v_0) = K_2 E(u_0) E(v_0)$ and this holds for all $u_0,v_0$, so $K_1 = K_2 = 1$, and the result is proven, specifically $C(u_0) = E(u_0)$ in $(Equ. 1)$.
